# googleスプレッドシートの起動時をトリガー（onOpen()など）としてgasが動かない

Tags: google-apps-script

googleスプレッドシートの起動時（スプレッドシートを開いたタイミング）に
スクリプトエディタで作成したgasを走らせたいのですが
次のようないずれの方法を試しても、起動時動作してくれません。

スクリプトエディタ上では、コード.gs（ディフォルト）スクリプトファイル内に
次のようにコードを書いた上で
個別に実行をすると動作するところまでは確認できています。

```
function test(){
    Browser.msgBox("Hello!");
}
```

1. スクリプトエディタのメインメニューから
   「編集」>「現在のプロジェクトのトリガー」をクリック。
   「新しいトリガーを追加」をクリックして、次の内容でトリガーを設定
   「test」>「スプレッドシートから」>「起動時」

スクリプトエディタおよびスプレッドシートを閉じて
スプレッドシートを再度開き直した際に
メッセージボックスで「Hello!」と表示されるはずなのですが表示されず。

2. 仕方ないので上記のトリガー設定を削除して
   「test」関数自体を次のように「onOpen」に書き直し

   ```
   function onOpen(){
       Browser.msgBox("Hello!");
   }
   ```

この状態でスクリプトエディタおよびスプレッドシートを閉じて
スプレッドシートを再度開き直した際に
メッセージボックスで「Hello!」と表示されるはずなのですが
これでもメッセージは表示されませんでした。

どちらも正規の手順通り操作をしているつもりなのですが
どこかに間違いがあったりするのでしょうか？
（ちなみにアカウント環境は、有料でのGスイートユーザーです）

以上、この現象に心当たりのある方、ご教示お願いします。

Answer (score 1):

提示のコードを私の環境で試してみたところ、1. 2. 両方とも動作しました。
特には問題なさそうに感じます。

どこに問題があるかチェックするために

- `Logger.log("hello!");` で function 自体が起動しているか確認
- `try { Browser.msgBox("hello!"); } catch(e) { Logger.log(e);}` で例外が起きてないか確認
- スプレッドシート自体を再作成してみる

といった方法で確認してみるのはいかがでしょうか。